# Should I save to Firestore from Android client or from Firebase Function?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an android app and I would like to know based on your experience what is better in terms of security and costs. I am not sure if it is better to save to the database from my client or from function. Looks like by communicating to firebase functions from my app and then writing to the database will be more expensive than just writing to the database from the app but Im willing to pay the price if it is more secure. Just want to know what you think about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of costs, there is no difference in writing data from the client or using cloud functions. No matter what you choose to use, the cost will be the same.

Regarding security, I recommend you read [Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started). So you can write your own security rules according to your app use-case.

Comment: Yeah, I have read about security rules, so you think it is safe enough by just implementing the security rules?

Comment: If you write the security rules in a correct way, definitely yes!